# Progress Bar Works on Emulator, but not phone

Tags: android

I have a custom notification that has a progress bar and 2 textviews in it. One for percentage and one for the name of the song downloading. The thing is it works in the Android Emulator, but it does not work on my phone. I sent the apk to my friend and he claims it works fine on his phone. What could be some causes of this?

Comment: a wild guess, do you have custom drawables? maybe only in one resolution? 2nd what is not working? is it not displayed? or looks bad? please provide some code so we can have a closer look.

Comment: The progress bar and textview are not custom drawable. But the little icon in the status bar when it is not pulled down is, but I am pretty sure I have all three resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plugging your phone into your development machine via a USB dongle, enabling development mode on the phone, and launching the app directly onto the device, as you would an AVD? If you do that, you can give us a stack trace, which would be more helpful.

Is the app running at all on your phone? Does it crash somewhere, or does it just swallow the error and fail to show the status bar?

Comment: I haven't tried doing that in a while because my computer wasn't reading my phone, but I will try again. It works and downloads the mp3 file, but it just doesn't show the progress going up in the progress bar or textview. The notification disappears onPostexecute as well, it's just not showing the progress. On the emulator it shows the progress bar and the textview counting up the percentage..